# How to make py.test ignore test args in decorator?

Tags: python, testing, mocking, decorator, pytest

I tried to made my custom mock class for py.test. I want to send mock_data in test, as first param. But py.test recognize it like fixture name, and raise exception. if remove `decorator.decorator` using, it losing fixtures in params.

```
from decorator import decorator

class mocker(object):
    ...
    def __call__(self, func):
        def patched(*args, **kwargs):
            self.setup_mocks()
            return func(self.mock_data, *args, **kwrgs)
        return decorator(patched, func)

...

@mocker
def test_some_func(mock_data, some_fixture):
    pass
```

rises it:

```
def (mock_data, some_fixture):
E       fixture 'mock_data' not found
...
```

Comment: In your real code is there a colon ':' after `def test_some_func(mock_data, some_fixture)`? If not, please edit your question to fully reflect your code.

Comment: thank, updated question.